# KafkaListener does not update jpa entity

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

**Background:**

I have a an entity with ***@Transactional*** on the class level. Below is an example, it contains everything needed for an entity.

```
@Entity   
Entity {
boolean flag;
}
```

I have a **JPA REPOSITORY**. And a **SERVICE** that uses the repository.

**Case 1:**

In the service I read the entity and update the flag in a utility method.

```
updateFlag(int id, boolean value){
value = repository.get(id);
value.setFlag(xyz);
}
```

The change is reflected in the database without any need for calling `repository.save(entity).`

**Case 2:**

After the above case runs, right after it KafkaListener runs and updates the entity with a new value but this time update is not reflected in the database unless I do `repository.save(entity).`

**Question:**

Why do we need to call save explicitly for the 2nd case and why it works in the first case even though they are same. Moreover, the method that updates the flag value is @Transactional which should persist the changes without need to call save. Any clues?

**Additional info:**

SQL Logs show that in case 1 there's an update query running. In case 2 there's only a select query running.

Comment: Maybe the entity is not dirty i.e. the change you made did not cause the entity state to actually change and hence not require an update statement.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` works on proxy mechanism.
So as long as you are not doing a save and in the consecutive line checking value it will persist the value

```
@Transactional
public int A(){
int id= myRepository.save(myEntity)
myRepository.get(id); //won't work because it hasn't been persisted yet
}
```

---

```
public int A(){
    call B();
    myRepository.get(id); //will work because it's been persisted 
}

@Transactional
public int B(){
   int id= myRepository.save(myEntity); // proxy works once execution point surpasses this method
}
```

mostly for the case 1 and case 2 you mentioned either of the above scenarios you are doing in your codebase

Comment: Your example is a bit wrong here, we are not calling save in any case here.  I get the entity

```@Transaction
updateEntity(){
entity = repository.get(id)
entity.setFlag()
}```

This updates and persists the value to the database. 

When I call the same method from KafkaListener  second time it doesn't do so. 

My understanding is it is because the first change is not written by save or saveAndFlush new changes won't have any effect.

Comment: Are you using any caching mechanism ?

Comment: No. I am not using any.